# Show progress of controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building **.NET Core** application and I want to change the text on the website based on the progress of controller actions. I wrote a short example below showing what I want to achieve. Some things are written in pseudo-code.

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHomeService _homeService;

    public HomeController(IHomeService homeService)
    {
        _homeService = homeService;
    }

    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        _homeService.ShowInfo(id);

        return View(model);
    }
```

**HomeService.cs**

```
public void FirstFunction()
{
    // write "Fetching results from database"
    ...
    // write "Results fetched successfully"
}

public void SecondFunction()
{
    // write "Parsing results"
    ...
    // write "Results parsed successfully"
}

public string ShowInfo(int id)
{
    FirstFunction();
    SecondFunction();
    return "Success!";
}
```

**functions.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        'url' : 'Home/Detail',
        'type' : 'GET',
        'data' : {
            'id' : 123
        },
        'success' : function(data) {
            // update some html element based on "write" commands in
            // FirstFunction() and SecondFunction()
        }
    });
}
```

How can I update HTML elements on web page with strings which FirstFunction and SecondFunctions "write"? The operations are quite long and I want to give the user some sort of information about what is happening right now.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to let `FirstFunction` and `SecondFunction` set some session variables, then on client side, use `setinterval` to trigger a get request to the server (using Ajax), which returns  the value of the session paramaters. Then display this to the user.